# Need to send Byte Array through Webservice in jmeter

Tags: web-services, arrays, jmeter

I am supposed to convert an image into array bytes and send it along with the destination location in a **Webservice**.
I have this code written in beanshell

```
File file = new File("\\PICS\\k6.jpg"); 
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int i=0;
for (int i; (i = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) 
{
bos.write(buffer, 0, i);
}
in.close();
 byte[] imageData = bos.toByteArray();
 bos.close();
 vars.put("imageData", new String(imageData));
```

I am facing this error-
An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.

The variable "imageData" seems to be in ASCII but how to send it along with the request.I need the array object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following line to the top of your script:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
```

and change the last line to look as follows:

```
vars.put("imageData", StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(new String(imageData)));
```

**UPD: ent-to-end code**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

File file = new File("/home/glinius/test.html");
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];    
for (int i; (i = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, i);
}
in.close();
byte[] imageData = bos.toByteArray();
bos.close();
vars.put("imageData", StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(new String(imageData)));
```

Comment: Its still not working Getting this error **Attempt to resolve method: escapeXml() on undefined variable or class name: StringEscapeUtils**  and the ASCII value in the variable no longer gets parsed.     
This is when I am using 2.11 while in 2.9 its still shows the previous error

Comment: Have just updated my answer with full code. It looks like that you don't have `import` statement that's why JMeter fails to recove StringEscapeUtils class

Comment: I had got it in the first time only but it doesn't work may be because how its being formulated by the Web service

Comment: Well I was able to do it Finally ,@ Dmitri,your code did help(phew...)
The developer didn't tell that it was supposed to be sent in **base64** format and hence the error kept coming