# How to pass an image to Jmeter web service call

Tags: web-services, testing, jmeter

Hi I m using JMeter to test a web service and I want to pass an image to that POST type web- Service using Jmeter. 
Actually that Web Service takes the image in the form of byte array and I want that I will pass image to jmeter either by referencing image path or any other possible way and that image should be converted to byte array and that byte array I can pass to the WEB Service.

Please note that I know how to call the web service with simple parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Check out

- [Need to send Byte Array through Webservice in jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142587/need-to-send-byte-array-through-webservice-in-jmeter/) question for solution
- and [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for explanation